# Calling functions in AngularJS service asynchronously from multiple controllers

Tags: angularjs

I have a AngularJS service with multiple methods in it.
Some of the methods are exposed to controllers for adding in process, which are processed by the service and then results are broadcasted by the service.

But I am not clear when in case my method is in process (method has not yet completed processing) and some controller calls the same method again. How to handle this case.

Also how can we make it sequential using something like semaphore.
I don't want to block the call to the service but make them execute in sequence. or it is already done by the AngularJS framework?

```
angular.module('MyAppModule').run(['MyService', function(MyService)
{
    MyService.initService();   
}])
.service('MyService', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope)
{
   this.initService = function()
   {
       // Init
   }  

   // This method is getting called async 
   // Also this method calls multiple methods inside this service 
   this.doSomeTask = function()
   {
       ....

       foo();

       ....
   }

   function foo()
   {
      // Done some long task
   }

   function foo2()
   {
      // Done some long task
   }

   this.doSomeTask2 = function()
   {
      .... 

      foo2();

      ....
   }

}]);
```

I have multiple methods in this service which are getting called from controllers asynchronously.

Comment: JavaScript is single threaded. If you have long tasks, in AngularJS, they can be broken up with the $timeout service which is a wrapper for window.setTimeout.

Comment: @georgeawg: not clear what you mean to say for $timeout.

Comment: See [AngularJS $timeout Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#when). $timeout allows other functions in the AngularJS event queue to process before doing the delayed function.